# Where can I find a copy of the 2018 Uniform Plumbing Code?

Tags: standards

My state, Texas, delegates to the Uniform Plumbing Code to establish standards,

> **Section 1301.255 adopts the Uniform Plumbing Code** and the International Code Council's International Plumbing Code as they existed on May 31, 2001. The statute notes that the Texas State Board of Plumbing Examiners may adopt later versions of this code.
>
> **As of June 2021, the 2018 edition of the Uniform Plumbing Code** and the 2018 edition of the International Code Council's International Plumbing Code **have been adopted by the State Board's Rule 367.2 in Title 22 of the Texas Administrative Code.**
>
> Rule 367.2 also adopts codes incorporated by reference within the 2018 International Plumbing Code, which include the International Code Council's 2018 International Fuel Gas Code and the 2018 International Residential Code.
>
> See the text of Rule 367.2 for details.

Where I can find the 2018 edition of the Uniform Plumbing Code? I know I can [buy one on Amazon for $200](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1944366075). Since this is a part of the Texas Occupation Code, can I find a copy for free anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a free copy, albeit with watermarks, here

- https://epubs.iapmo.org/2018/UPC/